# Android app not compatible with ASUS NEXUS 7

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility, nexus-7

I received a feedback for a published app from a user with a Asus Nexus 7 tablet: Google Play Store says the app is not compatible with the device.

I can't figure out why, I believe the Nexus 7 has everything the app needs, but I'm obviously missing something.

Here is the relevant manifest snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="2.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: I would suspect the Phone Permission.

Comment: Yes it could simply be the permissions, but then the app wouldn't be compatible with any tablet that does not support making phone calls. Have you tested the app on any other tablets?

Comment: I agree with the first comment. The original Nexus 7 doesn't have facility for a SIM card so doesn't have phone capability.

Comment: The nexus 7 does have a SIM card slot, at least the 3G Version, what it is missing is the ability to use the SIM to make phone calls.

Comment: Ok, phone permission is not vital to my app, but it is being used as optional feature. What <uses-feature ... required="false"/> should I add in order to have the phone permission where there is a phone, but let non-phone tablets install the app?

Comment: @XaverKapeller : I said the "original" Nexus 7. I've got one.

Comment: @LucioCrusca : Try `android.hardware.telephony` as the `<uses-feature ... required="false"/>` entry.

Comment: @Squonk I know you meant the original one, but like the 2013 model there is a 3G and a WIFI version. One has a SIM card slot, the other doesn't. But that is irrelevant to the question in both cases the nexus 7 doesn't support making phone calls.

Comment: @XaverKapeller : OK, let's rewind...I think we can both agree the original comment from user1704369 is likely to be the culprit based on the fact a Nexus 7 (any version) doesn't have phone ability. Based on permissions that imply features http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions it's most likely. You are right however, the app won't be compatible with any tablet without phone capability....perhaps the OP has only noticed the Nexus 7 is excluded so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its because of this permission ---

**uses-permission**

`android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"

your app user must be having asus nexus 7 Wi-fi only model.

Comment: And I was messing with other part of the project to get that fixed. This saved a lot of my time. Thanks. (y)

Comment: How to solve this problem to make compatible with this device?